# clickBubble: false not working

Tags: knockout.js

I've followed this example from the KO documentation article on the `click` binding [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html):

```
<div data-bind="click: myDivHandler">
    <button data-bind="click: myButtonHandler, clickBubble: false">
        Click me
    </button>
</div>
```

And my code looks like this:

```
<tr role="row" data-bind="click: 'True' === 'True' ? ($root.BrowsingCatalog() ? $root.viewProduct : $root.showProduct) : $root.showProduct">
    <td class="col-sm-1" data-bind="visible: 'True' == 'True' ? !$root.BrowsingCatalog() : true">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" data-bind="clickBubble: false" class="btn btn-round dropdown-toggle " aria-expanded="false">
                 <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span> 
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And when I click the `button`, the event from the `tr` gets called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**I solved it by setting `data-bind="click: function() { }, clickBubble: false"` on my `button`.**

Apparently, `clickBubble` without `click` won't work. If you want an event on an entire element except for a certain child element, setting `data-bind: "clickBubble: false"` on the child will not work, you also need to specifiy a binding for `click`, even if it's just an empty function...

Comment: I had to add `click: function() { return true }, clickBubble: false` but otherwise great solution!